# views_get_view() not accepting arguments?

Tags: views

Code without arguments works, but with arguments I run into an error of `EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format. Value at commerce_line_item()->commerce_product: . in EntityDrupalWrapper->set()`

This does not work:

```
    $array = array('228');
    $view = views_get_view('commerce_wishlist_page');
    $view->set_display("default");
    $view->pre_execute($array);
    $view->execute();
    print $view->render();
```

This works:

```
    $view = views_get_view('commerce_wishlist_page');
    $view->set_display("default");
    $view->execute();
    print $view->render();
```

Did they changed something? Because according to documentation this should work. I can confirm view work in views UI, also with handwritten contexual filters in UI. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

View "commerce_wishlist_page" was created by module itself. There appeared to be some problem with the view configuration itself, because when I re-created the view with exactly same values the error is gone. I think this is the module problem and possible typo somewhere in hook_install()